# Aggregating SharePoint lists

Tags: list, aggregation

We are designing a system with a national level, regional level and a sub-regional level.

We plan to implement this with a site structure with sub-sites and sub-sub-sites.

The sites at the lowest level will have a list.

One the level above we would like to have a list that contained all items from all subsites.

Is this possible without copying the list items?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved by using an SPSiteDataQuery. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx. This will require some programming.

If you do not want to develop against the SharePoint Object model, then use the Content Query Webpart (requires SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure feature activated). You will need to modify some XSLT in this scenario.

Another way is to use the DataView webpart and set scope to recursive. See: http://sympmarc.com/2008/02/19/rolling-up-content-in-sharepoint-using-the-data-view-web-part-dvwp/. This can be done from SharePoint Designer.